# Maximum Execution Time Exceeded Error while creating New Site in Multisite, Increasing Time Not working

Tags: multisite, fatal-error

I configured multisite on an existing site which is on Linux Server. Now when, I try to create new site on the network, it's giving me fatal error: execution time exceeded 30 seconds. I increased it to 500 (5min) (in .htacess,  yet it's giving me the same error, execution time exceeded 500s.

Why is it taking too much time to execute? How to solve the problem as increasing time limit is not helping in any case.

Note: I took backup of the same single site, and configured multisite on it using Localhost (wampp/windows). And it works perfectly fine there. No such issue occured.

Comment: I have added more detail to the question. Please, let me know what you don't understand.

Comment: When did this start to happen? Do you have a backup of the time before this issue?

Comment: This has started to happen after I configured multisite on my existing site.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that:

a) there are different values for the time set in .htaccess and wp-config. If it happens, WP uses the lower value. You should double check this.

b) you run out of memory on your server. This could happen if you use shared hosting